# How do I get my transition hamburger menu line to work in reverse in CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my hamburger menu to work, but it doesn't (not as I want to anyway). The animation transition works upon clicking the button the first time around, but upon clicking it again, it does the same thing. It should animate like a reverse transition of the first for the upon clicking.

```js
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile1")[0];

document.querySelector(".button-one").addEventListener("click", () => {
  a.classList.toggle("mobile2");
})
```

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px #000 solid;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px
}

.button-one {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 21px;
  width: 30px;
}

.mobile1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%
}

.mobile1 {
  background-color: currentColor;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  transition: top 250ms ease, transform 250ms ease 250ms;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 100%
}

.mobile2 {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile2 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="button-one">
  <div class="mobile1"></div>
</button>
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Is the extra curly brace in first piece of CSS (at the end) a copy/paste or typo error or does it exist in actual CSS?

Comment: It was a media query, right brace, that wasn't put in the snippet (amended)

Comment: `"upon clicking it again it does its own thing"` - can you describe that? Is it what we see in the above snippet  - the horizontal line that shifts up and then rotates but on reverse it does the opposite (move down and rotate)? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: On clicking it again, I want the line to rotate **then** move down

Comment: It is worth mentioning that using a `div` within a `button` does not meet the [HTML standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element). You can read more about allowed items within a `button` in the [Phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to update the `transition` CSS property of the `mobile1` class and add a `transition` property for the `mobile2` class since it should move reversely when the class is changed (user is clicked).

As an explanation;

- When the user clicks on it first time, move the line first and then transform it
- When the user clicks on it second time, transform the line first and then move it

```js
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile1")[0];

document.querySelector(".button-one").addEventListener("click", () => {
    a.classList.toggle("mobile2");
})
```

```css
    button{
        background: transparent;
        border:3px #000 solid;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        position:absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top:20px
    }
    
    .button-one{
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        height: 21px;
        width: 30px;
    }
    
    .mobile1 {
        background-color: black;
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%
    }
    
    
    .mobile1{
        background-color: currentColor;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:12px;
        transition: transform 250ms ease, top 250ms ease 250ms; **
        transform-origin: center;
        width:100%
    }
    
    .mobile2 {
        top:0;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    .mobile2 {
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
        transition: top 250ms ease, transform 250ms ease 250ms; **
    }
```

```html
<button class="button-one">
                <div class="mobile1">
                </div>
</button>
```

Comment: I had the transitions the other way round...

thanks for this...

Comment: You're welcome...